# Android - Two column layout

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I've a two column layout and want it working like the "Settings" on a android 4 on a tablet.

On the left a menu (it's a ListView) and depending on the action on the list view I want to load an activity on the right column.

How can I achieve this? I'm unsure of what keywords to use to search for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). What you would do is create an activity that allows for two fragments which you can customize how you want.